# How to pass object as hidden parameter with RedirectToAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have done like this.

```
public ActionResult GetInfo(SomeModel entity)
{
     ----
     return RedirectToAction("NewAction", "NewController", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(entity));
}
```

Action which was called

```
public ActionResult NewAction(SomeModel smodel)
{
     -------
     -------
}
```

This is working fine but I can see all posted param values on browser address bar, how can I hide these querystring param values in browser.

```
http://localhost:51545/NewController/NewAction?SurveyID=13&CatID=1&PrimaryLang=1&SurveryName=Test%20Survery&EnableMultiLang=False&IsActive=False
```

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your case instead of using `RouteValueDictionary` and passing model from querystring try `TempData`(because when we use RedirectToAction  it will make a new http request and object routes will be shown in url so its not a good approach to display sensitive data in url).

Use `TempData` as shown :-

```
public ActionResult GetInfo(SomeModel entity)
{
  ----
  TempData["entity"] = entity; //put it inside TempData here
  return RedirectToAction("NewAction", "NewController");
}

public ActionResult NewAction()
{
   SomeModel smodel = new SomeModel();
   if(TempData["entity"] != null){
   smodel = (SomeModel)TempData["entity"];  //retrieve TempData values here
   }
   -------
   -------
}
```

The benefit of using `TempData` here is that it will retain its value for one redirect and moreover model will be privately transported to another controller action and once you read data from `TempData` its data will be disposed automatically and if you want to retain `TempData` value after reading it then use `TempData.keep("entity")`.

---

OR

If your Views are in a same Controller then this a simple solution for your problem :

```
public ActionResult GetInfo(SomeModel entity)
{
  ----
  return NewAction(entity);
}

public ActionResult NewAction(SomeModel smodel)
{
   -------
   -------
  return View("NewAction",smodel)
}
```

As Correctly Commented by @Chips_100 so i m including it here :- The first solution will do a real redirect (302) which will update the URL in the users browser. The second solution will give the desired result while keeping the original URL in the address bar.

Comment: That looks overly complicated.  Isn't there a way to do a server side redirect?

Comment: @PhilipPittle..what complicated .. just you have put model inside tempdata and then typecast tempdata into model on desired action..what is complicated in it??

Comment: @Exception: Thanks it works
@ Philip Pittle: Some more efficient suggestion if any will be appreciated.

Comment: Keep in mind that there is a subtle difference for the user between the two solutions. The first will do a real redirect (302) which will update the URL in the users browser. The second solution will give the desired result while keeping the original URL in the address bar.

Comment: @Chips_100...yes see carefully in newaction while returning view i have also specified view name with it

Answer (score 0):

As it follows from your question, the hidden parameter is scoped to user session.

So you can store it into [`Session`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492995(v=vs.118).aspx) property of the controller:

```
public ActionResult GetInfo(SomeModel entity)
{
     Session["SomeKey"] = "SomeValue";
     return RedirectToAction("NewAction", "NewController");
}
```

After that you can retrieve it (another controller also works here):

```
public ActionResult NewAction(SomeModel smodel)
{
     var parameter = Session["SomeKey"] as string;

     // Remove the parameter from session storage
     Session.Remove("SomeKey");

     // Do the stuff using provided parameter value

}
```